# Python split list based on N chunks AND positional number in string

Tags: python, string, list, split

I want to split a string of lists in (almost) equal chunks but also take a number inside the list of strings into account.
Example:

```
def split(a, n):
    k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
    return (a[i*k+min(i, m):(i+1)*k+min(i+1, m)] for i in range(n))


l = ["string-1-1", "string-1-2", "string-2-1", "string-2-2", "string-2-3"]
chunks = 2
l_split = list(split(l, chunks))
```

Which results into

```
[['string-1-1', 'string-1-2', 'string-2-1'], ['string-2-2', 'string-2-3']]
```

However I would like the following result:

```
[['string-1-1', 'string-1-2'], ['string-2-1', 'string-2-2', '-2-3']]
```

So the list should be split in the total amount of `N` chunks, but the split should only occur after the number on the first position (`N-N`) reaches the next value.
The numbers in the string can be multiple digits (e.g. `12-24`), but wil only ever be 2 numbers (e.g. `N-N`).

Comment: why is it ```'-2-3'``` not ```'string-2-3'``` in the result?

Comment: It's not clear what the parameter `n` does. What if you passed in an `n` of `4` in the above example?  It seems like the constraint `split should only occur after the number on the first position (N-N)` may not be compatible with a given `n`. Why not just split on the `N-N` string?

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is not clear but I understand that you want to split the list into sublists based on the given chunk size

So, you are not required to divmod. I'm not sure but this may be help you

```
[a[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(a), n)]
```